# PHP check if 3 counts later (date)(Cycle of 1-7)

Tags: php, math, radix

I'm currently making a system which needs to know if a certain variable has been stored less than 3 days ago, and if it has, return true. When the variable was initially saved, it was set as date('N'), which is the day of the week, in numerical format. (1 = monday, 7 = sunday according to php docs.)

However, how would I figure out that it's been 3 or more days later? My main dilemma is this: if the variable is day 5, and it is currently day 4, that means the cycle of 1 week is almost complete (6 days have passed) - however I can't figure out how to do that in php. Another example would be the variable is day 7, and it is currently day 1 - numerically speaking, inclusively there are 6 "days" in between the two values, but in reality, it has only been one day as after 7 comes 1.

P.S. I reset the values every week, which is why I do not bother to save things like month, or year.

Comment: Can't you just dumb it into a datetime and then compare the two of them? Something like `new DateTime(date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . $yourdate . " 00:00:00");` then just diff them?

Comment: Or use unix timestamps. if the difference is greater than 3 (days) * 24 (hours/day) * 3600 (seconds/hr), then... That makes the math so much easier (all integers).

Comment: This is extremely simple math. Can you at least show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be solved in the current state with the help of mathematics. Let's first take a look at *good* and *bad* values.

- stored on `1`: *good*: 2, 3, 4 *bad*: 1, 5, 6, 7
- stored on `2`: *good*: 3, 4, 5 *bad*: 1, 2, 6, 7
- stored on `6`: *good*: 7, 1, 2 *bad*: 3, 4, 5, 6
- stored on `7`: *good*: 1, 2, 3 *bad*: 4, 5, 6, 7

If you subtract the stored value from the current, you'll see that `good - stored = 1, 2 or 3` for standard cases (no overlapping) and `good - stored = -6, -5, -4` (maximum overlapping).

Meanwhile `bad - stored = 4, 5, 6 or 0` (no overlapping) and `bad - stored = -3, -2, -1 or 0` (maximum overlapping).

So you want your result to be either in the interval [1, 3] or [-6, -4], which could be done like this

```
//somwhere $storedN is defined
$todayN = date('N');
$result = $todayN - $storedN;
if (($result > 0 && $result < 4) || ($result > -7 && $result < -3)) {
//            no overlap                        overlap
    // valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are saving your dates as strings, one approach is to use epoch time:

```
echo time();  //1403218504
```

The large number you see is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

There are 3600 * 24 seconds in a day. Therefore when you save your "variable"'s date in epoch time, to see if it was more than 3 days ago, you can do

```
$one_day = 3600*24;

$now = time();
$before = $your_old_time;

if ($now - $before > ($one_day * 3)) {
  //$before is older than 3 days
}
```